# Passing Customer Jouney Reference into Dynamics 365 Workflow

Tags: reference, workflow, dynamics-365, dynamics-marketing

[image]

When trying to reference the customer journey in a workflow this way, it seems to not get any values despite being triggered from a customer journey using the 'Launch Workflow' option. Is there a solution to this issue?

Comment: I suspect, Regarding for Twilo Message Entity does not support Customer Journey Entity. Try creating Twilo Message record per hand and try to add regarding as Customer Journey for Test. If this works then it shall also work with workflows.

Comment: Source Customer Journey property on contacts is populated only in few cases - like marketing form being submited as a response to email campaign for example. It is not populated by default for all contacts flowing trough journey.